Close all Firefox windows
Is there a (built-in) way to close all windows in a Firefox session (preferably without manually closing each window)?
I would prefer an extension-free solution; I also would like to keep enabled the setting that re-opens all windows from the previous session upon starting Firefox.
I am on MacOS 15. Asking about an application-level solution given Chrome's 'Close all windows' which is not OS specific. It may just be a feature request I should put in. A quick google on a MacOS-specific solution suggests ⌘+⌥+W should close all open windows, but that doesn't seem to work.

What OS are you working in? This is a function of the OS or window manager you're using, not really of the application. Windows, for instance, has a "Close All Windows" option when you right click on any stacked application icon in the task bar.

Noting I also use Windows and Linux, so would appreciate a general solution.

I don't think that "general solution" is appropriate for this site. Unless FF has integrated some means of doing this on all their supported platforms in their core codebase, no such "general solution" exists. That the fact FF runs on platforms that are not multi-window (mobile) seems to me a good indication they have left certain aspects of the window management to each host OS. Your question about MacOS is narrow enough to answer with the authority you need and this site requires. If you have a specific OS you'd ALSO like the same answer to, ask the question for that OS.

feature request

Command + Option + Q Closes all windows of your current app on Mac.
This will close all windows for the app but keep the app "open." To completely close the app, follow up with Command + Q.
Apple Article

*⌘+⌥+W, also for some reason this doesn't seem to work for Firefox on an M3 Mac :(

pressing cmd + shift + w will close the active window. if you have 2 windows just do it twice, for 3 press 3 times etc. If you prefer tab by tab try cmd + w
or Use the keyboard shortcut cmd+Shift+Q

Thank you - unfortunately, I have sessions with 10s of windows which makes manually closing each inconvenient. I am looking for a single button/shortcut.

you could also try writing a custom shell script. I do not know shell script personally, but if you were interested you could always try.

Use the keyboard shortcut cmd+Shift+Q

A shell script/Automater task is possible but pretty hacky, preferably an application-level solution. ⌘+Shift+Q logs you out.

mac os is a unix like os. based off of the linux kernel.
